# Unable to send images from one Activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send an image taken by a camera from one activity to another activity. I have tried it by the following two methods(from stackoverflow)

**Method 1:**

**Passing Image via Path :**

```
String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Pictures" + File.separator + "SanPics2";
Intent image_intent = new Intent(Snap_ImageView.this,FullScreen.class);
                        image_intent.putExtra("image_path" ,path );
                        System.out.println("Inent has passed the extras");
                        startActivity(image_intent);
```

**On Receiving End(FullScreen.java) :**

```
final String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_Path");
Bitmap org_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
imageview.setImageBitmap(org_bitmap);
```

This method doesn't seem to set the image but it reaches the destination activity and shows a plain white background, weird !! The Logcat for method 1 is as follows :

**Method 1 Logcat :**

```
12-26 18:57:01.520: D/dalvikvm(6137): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 897K, 35% free 9156K/13955K, paused 221ms, total 221ms
12-26 18:57:01.970: D/dalvikvm(6137): GC_CONCURRENT freed 88K, 11% free 40280K/45191K, paused 28ms+28ms, total 96ms
12-26 18:57:02.790: I/System.out(6137): /storage/sdcard0/Pictures/SanPics2
12-26 18:57:06.270: I/System.out(6137): Inent has passed the extra
12-26 18:57:06.280: I/Choreographer(6137): Skipped 302 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Doesn't report on any problem but at the same time doesn't set the image expected.

**Method 2:**

**Passing Image via ByteArray :**

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

**On Receiving End(FullScreen.java) :**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

This method doesn't reach the destination activity at all.

**Method 2 Logcat :**

```
12-26 19:04:12.620: D/dalvikvm(7237): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1322K, 34% free 9244K/13955K, paused 144ms, total 169ms
12-26 19:04:12.860: D/dalvikvm(7237): GC_CONCURRENT freed 90K, 11% free 40366K/45191K, paused 25ms+14ms, total 73ms
12-26 19:04:14.350: I/System.out(7237): /storage/sdcard0/Pictures/SanPics2
12-26 19:04:19.850: I/System.out(7237): Inent has passed the extra
12-26 19:04:19.930: I/Choreographer(7237): Skipped 454 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

This is as same as Method 1 Logcat. I am totally lost here cause neither of the methods work and I am unable to find whats happening inside. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.
It'll be great if either one of the activity can be made to work.

**NOTE :**

I am calling both the styles of intent within the below depicted code :

```
Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);
                    view_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Pictures" + File.separator + "SanPics2";
                    System.out.println(path);
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System
                            .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream byte_array_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, byte_array_stream);
                        byte[] byte_array = byte_array_stream.toByteArray();
                        ****Intent image_intent = new Intent(Snap_ImageView.this,FullScreen.class);
                        image_intent.putExtra("image_path" ,byte_array );//Similarly path intent style at the same position
                        System.out.println("Inent has passed the extra");
                        startActivity(image_intent);****
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();

                    }
```

Does this have anything to do with the restriction of image display at destination activity ? I am just a fresher so i apologize if these kinda questions sound silly to ya. Cheers !!

Comment: Perhaps its simpler to have a class extend Application and use it as a shared object

Comment: When I execute the first method, the program reaches the point till it sets the image in destination activity. After the statement imageview.setImageBitmap(org_bitmap); I used a log message which gets printed accurately but the image is not set !!!! I find it really difficult to digest. Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had not given the image extension along with the file name. That was the problem that I had. Method 1 works well if you add the following :

```
String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Pictures" + File.separator + "SanPics2";
File file = new File(path,"Your image name.jpg");//**Extension is what matters**
String image_name = file.toString();
Intent image_intent = new Intent(Snap_ImageView.this,FullScreen.class);
                        image_intent.putExtra("image_path" ,image_name );
                        System.out.println("Inent has passed the extras");
                        startActivity(image_intent);
```

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

so what do you want? you have already saved photo and need to open it from another activity?

Put it to the indent and sent it

```
filepath = "Your Image Path"
intent.putExtra("imagePath", filepath);
```

Receive it from Another Activity

```
String image_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
myimageview.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
```

and let me know if i got you wrong!

**Edited:**

As you reqested, convertion of Drawable from Bitmap

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.cam_image);
```

or try this

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)ur_drawable).getBitmap();
```

Comment: You got me right.Thats more or less same as what I have done but when i try to implement what you've suggested, it says that setImageDrawable(drawable) accepts only drawable argument and not a bitmap object. How do I convert drawable to bitmap ? Thanks for your suggrstion though.

Comment: Let me find something for you

Comment: Thats so great pal. Keep that spirit up !!

Comment: I dont get what you mean. My file exists in the specified folder and not in the drawable !!

Comment: Nah, I take a picture and store it in a specified folder at SDcard such as sdcard/pictures/sanpics2 !!

Comment: myimageview.setImageBitmap(image); try this. but actually no big difference between these two

Comment: Thats exactly what I have tried but I humbly request you to go through my question again cause you have suggested the same thing what I have tried initially. Appreciate your effort though.

Comment: So what you're asking is how to set a Bitmap to an imageView's source. Not how to pass an image from one activity to another

Comment: @MobileMon I have an image taken by Camera Intent in one activity and want to pass the image to next activity to add some effects. I am able to display the image taken via camera in the same activity but I want it in the second activity and not in the activity where I actually take the picture . I think you got my point. Thanks anyways.